# How do I reply with mention pycord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am running a discord bot. But it responds without mentioning.

In discord.py I could do something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.reply("Hello!", mention_author=True)
```

And it would mention the user and reply to their message. But since discord.py was depricated, I switched to pycord. And I just can't find how I can do the same thing in pycord.

Here is simple echo bot to replicate:

```
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")


@bot.slash_command(name="chat", description="some desc")
async def chat(ctx, msg):
    await ctx.respond(msg)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The result I want to achieve, but with slash command
[image]

Comment: You could just mention the user in the message itself. It would be ctx.user.mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to mention the user would be:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="chat", description="some desc")
async def chat(ctx, msg):
    await ctx.response.send_message(f"{ctx.user.mention} {msg}")  
    # f string with user mention
```

It mentions the user from the string returned from `.mention`.

Because you're using slash commands (and in the example output, it's a text command), the bot can't mention the user (without using the above method) without a message object.

One way to get that message object [would be](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message):

```
ctx.message
```

You can reply to this message instead as well.

[Documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.ClientUser.mention)

Comment: Note: may edit this later, because I did find a message object in context in docs. I am also neglecting my chem homework

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reply to a message you would use `response.send_message()`, not respond

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="chat", description="some desc")
async def chat(ctx, msg):
    await ctx.response.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: it replies without tagging as well